# How to pass a custom parameter to Connect To DataBase Keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have been using Connect To DataBase Keyword in Robot Framework. Is it possible to add a custom parameter to the keyword?
For ex : i want to add dictionary=true to cursor instance below is the keyword that i have used -

> EMPDB.Connect To Database    pymysql  ${EMPNAME}  ${EMPUSER}   ${PWD}   ${HOST}   ${PORT}

To Above Keyword statement can i use dictionary=true? So that when i select query the result i want is along with the column and the values.

Answer (score 2):

That's is not possible using the library as is, so you need to implement that feature yourself. Usually DB queries return lists and they do not include column names.